# Is there anyway to present a native controller to a TabBarIOS with React Native?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-ios

I wanna integrate a TabBarIOS into native App. Such as presenting to a TabBarIOS after hit a button.
But it crushed when I run.

In **index.ios.js**

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
} from 'react-native';

import myTabBar from './ios/tab/MyTab.js'
AppRegistry.registerComponent('myTabBar', () => myTabBar);
```

**native code:**

```
let rootView = RCTRootView(
        bundleURL: jsCodeLocation,
        moduleName: "myTabBar",
        initialProperties: nil,
        launchOptions: nil
    )
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.view = rootView
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**the error:**

```
2016-11-16 15:56:51.600 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Running application "myTabBar" with appParams: {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{}}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
2016-11-16 15:56:51.611 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: Native component for "RCTImageView" does not exist
2016-11-16 15:56:51.611 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Warning: Native component for "RCTVirtualImage" does not exist
2016-11-16 15:56:51.738 swift-2048[5277:144989] -[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7febe1099c00
2016-11-16 15:56:51.739 [error][tid:main][RCTUIManager.m:1100] Exception thrown while executing UI block: -[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7febe1099c00
2016-11-16 15:56:51.758 swift-2048[5277:144989] -[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7febe1099c00
2016-11-16 15:56:51.759 swift-2048[5277:144989] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RCTCustomScrollView refreshControl]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7febe1099c00'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't post screenshot of code, post code directly instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that it can't find `RCTImageView`, I'm guessing you haven't included the library.

If you're using CocoaPods, you'll want it to include `RCTImage`, and have it look a little something like:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'YourApp' do
  use_frameworks!

  # React Native
  pod 'React', :path => 'node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'RCTImage',
  ]
end
```